# Stack pop/push segmentation fault wrong same numbers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, return, stack

I'm writing a stack that's a linked list of data (void type). The data I am testing, is

```
struct my_data {
    int val;
    char name[60];
};

struct my_stack_node {
void *data;
struct my_stack_node *next;
};

struct my_stack {
int size;
struct my_stack_node *first;
};
```

the data used to be pushed, is initialized like this:

```
    s1 = my_stack_init(sizeof(struct my_data));
    if (!s1) {
        puts("Error in my_stack_init()");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\ns1 initialized, size of data: %lu\n", sizeof(struct my_data));

    for (int i = 0; i < NODES; i++) {
        data = malloc(sizeof(struct my_data)); // We must allocate static memory
        data->val = i;
        sprintf(data->name, "Value %d", i);
        if (my_stack_push(s1, data)) {
            puts("Error in my_stack_push()");
            exit(1);
        }
     } //s1 is the stack we are using here
```

And pushing them by my_stack_push(s2, data); stack and the data as the arguments.

My push function is this one:

```
int my_stack_push(struct my_stack *stack, void *data){

        if(stack == NULL && sizeof(data)> 0){
                printf("Null Stack or data size error.\n");
                //la pila debe existir
                return -1;
        }
        else {

        struct my_stack_node *nodeToPush = malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));
                nodeToPush -> data = data;
                if(stack -> first == NULL) {
                        nodeToPush -> next = NULL;
                        stack -> first = nodeToPush;
                }
                else {
                        nodeToPush -> next = stack -> first;
                        stack -> first = nodeToPush;
                }
        }
        return 0;

    }
```

And my pop function is this one

```
void *my_stack_pop(struct my_stack *stack){
        struct my_stack_node *node = stack->first;
        if(stack->first == NULL){
        return 0;
        }
        stack->first = node->next;
        void *ret = node->data;
        free(node);
        return ret;
}
```

But in my main, when I pop them and try to compare them, I get a segmentation fault:

```
while ((data1 = my_stack_pop(s1))) {
    data2 = my_stack_pop(fs1);
    printf("Node of s1: (%d, %s)\t", data1->val, data1->name);
    printf("Node of fs1: (%d, %s)\n", data2->val, data2->name);
    if (!data2 || data1->val != data2->val || my_strcmp(data1->name, data2->name)) {
        printf("Data in s1 and fs1 are not the same.\n (data1->val: %d <> data2->val: %d) o (data1->name: %s <> data2->name: "
               "%s)\n",
               data1->val, data2->val, data1->name, data2->name);
        exit(1);
    }
    size1 = sizeof(*data1);
    size2 = sizeof(*data2);
    free(data1);
    free(data2);
}
printf("size of data from s1: %d\t", size1);
printf("size of data from fs1: %d\n", size2);
```

(the 2 stacks are a copy of each other so what I inputed, should be the same I read). When I return the whole node in the pop function (not the data, but the whole my_stack_node), everything is right.. but wrong:

```
Comparing the data...
```

Node of s1: (0, Value 0) //good one
Node of fs1: (0, Value 0)
8 
8

Node of s1: (-1203217792, NV) //here it begins to go all wrong
Node of fs1: (-1203217792, NV)
8 
8

Node of s1: (-1203217792, NV)
Node of fs1: (-1203217792, NV)
8 
8

Node of s1: (-1203217792, NV)
Node of fs1: (-1203217792, NV)
8 
8

Node of s1: (0, )
Node of fs1: (0, )
double free or corruption (fasttop)
Aborted (core dumped)

Size is the same as the data inputed, but the value and name are bad (even in the non copied stack), which is supposed to be:

```
New node in s1: (0, Value 0)
New node in s1: (1, Value 1)
New node in s1: (2, Value 2)
New node in s1: (3, Value 3)
New node in s1: (4, Value 4)
New node in s1: (5, Value 5)
New node in s1: (6, Value 6)
New node in s1: (7, Value 7)
New node in s1: (8, Value 8)
New node in s1: (9, Value 9)
```

But when I return (on my stack pop) the data itself like in the code, I get core dumped in the print of the test.(data that has 8 bytes of length, like the one input).

When I return the node (size = 64) it prints correctly wrong data, but when I return the data(size = 8 (like the one pushed)), it core faults.

If I push the same data and read the same data (as it shown when I return node because even when weird output, are the same), why do I get a core segmentation fault when I return the data that's supposed to print like the example above?

It looks that it only happens when I read the data2, and not data1. This is the code I use to write and read the file :

Write:

```
int my_stack_write(struct my_stack *stack, char *filename){
        int count = 0;
        struct my_stack_node *aux =malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));
        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "wb");

        if(stack->first != NULL){
                aux = stack->first;
                count++;
                while(aux->next != NULL){
                        printf("New node in s1: (%p)\n", aux->data);
                        fwrite(aux ,sizeof(struct my_stack_node), 1, file);
                        aux = aux->next;
                        count++;
                }
                printf("New node in s1: (%p)\n", aux->data);
                fwrite(aux ,sizeof(struct my_stack_node), 1, file);

        }
        fclose(file);
        return count;
}
```

Read:

```
struct my_stack *my_stack_read(char *filename){
        struct my_stack *stackRead = my_stack_init(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));
        struct my_stack_node *stackNode = malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));
        FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb");

        if(!file){
                puts("Impossible obrir el fitxer");
                return NULL;
        }else{

                while(fread(stackNode, sizeof(struct my_stack_node), 1, file)){

                                printf("New node in fs1: (%p)\n", stackNode->data);
                                stackNode = (struct my_stack_node*) stackNode;
                                my_stack_push(stackRead, stackNode->data);
                }
                fclose(file);
                struct my_stack *InvertedStack = my_stack_init(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));
                struct my_stack_node *aux = malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));

                while(my_stack_len(stackRead) !=0){
                printf("Inverting the stack\n");
                aux = my_stack_pop(stackRead);
                my_stack_push(InvertedStack, aux);
                }
                return InvertedStack;
        }
}
```

Thank you to anyone that helps.

MCVE of the program, so people can check the whole code and help better:

test2.c:

https://codeshare.io/244eN4

my_lib.c:
https://codeshare.io/G7L8Ab

my_lib.h:

https://codeshare.io/5DzZOm

With this, you should have a broader view and an executable once compiled on what's happening to me.

Comment: `... void *data)` `sizeof(data)> 0` `nodeToPush -> data = data;` . `sizeof(data)` is equal to `sizeof(void*)` it's a void generic pointer, not the data to push. Is `data` a pointer to memory with auto storage duration? Why don't you pass `sizeof(data)` along with the pointer and allocate memory for it to copy by value? Can you post example how do you call `my_stack_push`?

Comment: What is `struct my_stack_node`? How is the stack initialized?

Comment: Don't `malloc` into `nodeToPush` before testing for NULL

Comment: @4386427 I've got another output now, first iteration is good, but others fail. I'll put my_stack_node struct

Comment: `fread(stackNode, sizeof(struct my_stack_node), ...`  `my_stack_push(stackRead, stackNode->data);` Where does the data point to? To an automatically allocated memory? Are you trying to run `my_stack_write` and `my_stack_read` in different runs of the program? Pointer values can't be reliably saved to disc - move to `fprintf` and `fscanf`... I can guess that`data` points to memory that no longer exists or is not valid.  Can you create a full MCVE, including main function?   `stackNode = (struct my_stack_node*) stackNode;` is a NOP.

Comment: @KamilCuk data is the data inside the struct, which is a void. removed that "(struct my_stack_node*) " but the program still double free or corruption (fasttop)
Aborted (core dumped) on me

Comment: `data` can't be `void`. `void` is an incomplete type. `data` is a void _pointer_. Where is the memory it _points_ to? How is it allocated? How is it deallocated? Using auto storage duration (on stack)? You are saving the pointer _value_ to the file, not the data itself. Thus you are reading _pointers_ to some memory region. So, how and from where is the `int my_stack_push(struct my_stack *stack, void *data)` called when the `my_stack` is initialized with new/initial data (not when reading from file)?

Comment: @KamilCuk data in this case is a "my_data" struct, but I don't know it in the progrma itself (the struct is in the test), data itself is passed as a parameter to my_stack_push and then stored, to be returned on my_stack_pop, and in the test (where it's returned), I read this return as a my_data. First iteration goes well (0 Value 0 in both) but then it "breaks", and I don't know where.

Comment: `data` in this case is a void pointer to memory region holding "my_data" struct data. How is this _pointer_ obtained? Can you show the code which allocates/initializes the my_data struct, to which a pointer is obtained which then (the pointer) is passed to the function that pushes data up to the stack?

Comment: @KamilCuk just put the initialitzation of s1

Comment: Code is pretty long, I can facilitate it so you can look as a whole and test it yourself

Comment: Cool, we allocate `data` using `malloc` so we use dynamic storage duration. As the question become pretty long, if you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including main function and so on, you will get help much faster.

Comment: @KamilCuk Just set 3 codeshare links with the code enough to execute it and have a broader view of the code.

Comment: It is useless to execute that code, read and write do not works on the expected data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designing good, reliable and consistent API and libraries is a very hard job, especially in programming languages in which creating interfaces is somewhat harder then in object oriented languages.

I mean to be really nice, but the code you posted has memory leaks, unhandled errors, undefined behavior and bad design. The sizeof operator is misused. I can only guess you fail to understand how the memory allocation really works and the concept of a pointer and general `void*` pointer.

Well, let's go.

So the reasons the code will seg fault is:

1. As suspected, the data to which the stack points is invalid. Indeed it is `malloc`ated, but is subsequently `free`d some lines later:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NODES; i++) {
    struct ... * data = malloc(sizeof(struct my_data));
    my_stack_push(s1, data); // pushes the data pointer to the stack
    void *data1 = my_stack_pop(s1); // pops the data pointer to the stack
    ...
    assert(data1 == data); // data and data1 are the same
    free(data1); // and data get's freed
    // the memory behind both data and data1 is freed in this point
    // thus the pointer s1.first->node->data is invalid
    // as the code runs in loop, effectively all the data in this stack are invalid
}
```

2. You double free pointer in the `main()` in the while loop. Both `s1` and `fs1` are obtained from calling `my_stack_read` on the same file - thus logically they should contain the same values. As they store the same values, stored pointers to data are the same, thus freeing the pointer will also free and invalidate the second pointer in the second list. Double free is undefined behavior and I guess should result in something similar to segmentation fault on normal systems.

```
while ((data1 = my_stack_pop(s1))) {
    data2 = my_stack_pop(fs1);
    ...
    assert(data1 == data2); // same pointers
    free(data1);
    free(data2); // double free corruption - seg fault
}
```

- After fixing the errors the code will run and print "All tests passed", live version available [here](https://onlinegdb.com/HyormX3-4). Anyway below are some notes:

  3. There is no need to allocate an array of stacks in `my_stack_init`:

```
struct my_stack *my_stack_init(int size){
    struct my_stack *stack = malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack_node) * size);
    ...
```

`stack` now points to `size` count of `sizeof(struct my_stack_node)` bytes of memory. You need only a single my_stack_node structure. Also, `sizeof` returns `size_t`. A better version would be:

```
struct my_stack *my_stack_init(size_t size){
    struct my_stack *stack = malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));
    ...
```

4. `my_stack_read` leaks memory:

```
struct my_stack_node *aux = malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));
...
aux = my_stack_pop(stackRead);
```

5. Indentation in the code you posted is a bit off. Try to keep one indentation style, I could advertise the good old' [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/process/coding-style.html) but you can use anything but be consistent. Also your code could use some restructuring - limiting the scope of variables or like removing `else` after `return NULL` may increase readability.
6. `sizeof` returns `size_t`. The proper way to print `size_t` is to use `"%zu"` printf modifier. You can print pointers by casting to `void*` and using `"%p"` printf modifier.
7. Generally, this is really good work, but you need to understand that pointers point to data and are data themselves (as they have value). Currently your implementation stores only pointers to the data, thus client code is responsible for freeing the pointers. It's easy to trap yourself in confusion in such implementation. One could rewrite your stack implementation to allocate memory for the node *and* for the data itself, thus freeing the need for client code to handle the memory in any special manner. It could look like:

```
int my_stack_push(struct my_stack *stack, void *data) {
   ...
   // allocate memory for new link in the list
   struct my_stack_node *nodeToPush = malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));
   if (nodeToPush == NULL) abort();
   // allocate memory for data itself
   nodeToPush->data = malloc(stack->size);
   if (nodeToPush->data == NULL) abort();
   // memory copy the data into the pointer
   memcpy(nodeToPush->data, data, stack->size);
   ..
```

In such implementation the stack is responsible in freeing the pointer and stores only copies of the data. Thus all the handles need to be rewritten to support that. The size of the data is available via `stack->size` and initialized in `my_stack_init` with the argument.

8. Storing pointers value in a file seems like a bad idea from serialization point of view. Pointer values change in between runs. Storing pointers to list elements feels exactly bad. It's better to store the memory of the data itself, I see no reason in storing the pointer values of the list. Note that in current implementation the value of `stackNode->next` is indeed not used in `my_stack_read`, because it's value has been freed already before.  I fail to see why do you even write the value of `stackNode->next` to the file if you never use it.

So we can store the data itself in the file:

```
int my_stack_write(struct my_stack *stack, char *filename){
    ...
    node = stack->first;
    void *data = node->data;
    // write the data behind the node to the file
    if (fwrite(data, stack->size, 1, file) != 1) {
         return -100;
    }
}
```

In a similar way we could rewrite `my_stack_read`:

```
struct my_stack *my_stack_read(char *filename, size_t size) {
     ...
     struct my_stack *stack = stack_init(size);
     ...
     void *newdata = malloc(stack->size);
     while (fread(newdata, stack->size, 1, file)) {
           my_stack_push(stack, newdata);
     }
     free(newdata); // as in my proposed implementation my_stack stores copy
     // of the memory behind the pointers, we can safely manage own memory
     // by freeing the pointer

}
```

Comment: Just managed to make it work with your help. Just to explain things: It's not work, I'm still a student,and I'm doing this to learn and create templates for generic structures, so thanks for pointing out everything and ELI5. And about the identation: I'm terrible at making posts in stackoverflow, but all my code is always idented in vim with "gg=G" for a standard identation, which works fine for me.

Really thank you and @bruno for the help.

Answer (score 2):

you have problems in `my_stack_pop`

```
void *ret =  malloc(sizeof(struct my_stack_node));
ret = node->data;
```

The *malloc* is useless (and create a memory leak), and you miss to free *node* too

You can replace these 2 lines by :

```
void * ret = node->data;

free(node);
```

---

Other remarks

- in `my_stack_push` check the error *before* to do the allocation, or free *nodeToPush* in case of the error else you have a memory leak
- `sizeof(x)` where *x* is a `void*` will always values 4 if you are on a 32b CPU, and 8 if it is a 64b CPU. *sizeof* is not *strlen* for instance

---

Finally concerning *the 2 stacks are a copy of each other so what I inputed, should be the same* it is difficult to help you because you do not say how you cloned the stack

---

(remarks after your edit)

In `my_stack_write`

- do not initialize *aux* with an allocation, you again have a memory leak doing that.
- to dump the memory of `my_stack_node` do not work, your goal is to save the data (contains of `my_data`), not the cell pointing to the data

In `my_stack_read`

- it is useless to use a dynamic allocation for `my_stack_node`, it can be placed into the stack ( `struct my_stack_node stackNode;` ), else do not forget to free it because you again introduce a memory leak.
- same error when you read a `my_stack_node`, you have to read the saved data (a `my_data`)
- `stackNode = (struct my_stack_node*) stackNode;` that does nothing because it sets *stackNode* with itself
- `my_stack_push(stackRead, stackNode->data);` does not have the expected result because `stackNode->data` has a wrong value read in the file.

Both read and write are wrong, this is why the two stack do not have the same contents

Comment: looks like I didn't push the right type of data when I was reading. but now it gets weirder on the output, I suppose from not freeing memory. (Editing the post)

Comment: Just changed the error output and my new pop and push functions

Comment: Allocated the nodeToPush after the NULL check. Thanks for the explanation on the sizeof. (getting an error, though is different now).

Comment: @flaixman I updated my answer, please reread it, both `my_stack_write`  and `my_stack_read` are wrong

Comment: thanks, I'll try to fix it. Just shared the code so people can execute it to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Currently to execute your code is useless, read and write are wrong ;-)